# Which example can reveal hypothesis test is not always valid?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

As to

> hypothesis test is not 100% exact

I want to get an example to prove above logion.
The example may be:

1. normal distribution
2. t.test p value > 0.05(even > 0.5,perfect statistic result)
3. but 2 population is totally not same

what's that kind of example?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Who / what are you quoting? What was the context? What is intended by "not exact" there? What is the function of the restrictions you're placing? How do those restrictions relate to the context of the quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any test you use will be tuned by the parameter signification - usually set to 5% and sometimes 1% or 0.1%. It is equal to the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it's true (an error known as type I error).

Therefore, if the null hypothesis is true, there is a probability (usually 5%) of erroneously rejecting it.

We can even run a simulation on it. Let's perform the following hypothesis test:

$$\left \{
 \begin{matrix}
 H_0: \mu = 0 \\
 H_1: \mu \ne 0
 \end{matrix}
\right.
$$

I'm going to simulate 100 samples of size 5 from a normal distribution with mean equal 0, that is, the null hypothesis is true. I'm listing the p-values resulting from performing the t-test on each sample.

```
> n<-5
> nm<-100
> d<-1
> alfa<-.05
> pval<-vector(length=nm)
> for (i in 1:nm) {
+   x1<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=1)
+   pval[i]<-t.test(x1,alternative ="two.sided",var.equal = TRUE )[["p.value"]]
+ }
> pval[order(pval)]
  [1] 0.004713230 0.004759158 0.015790830 0.016651239 0.018606903 0.035737205 0.039671202 0.047414758
  [9] 0.051332632 0.061682234 0.062405171 0.074853704 0.082323971 0.087110016 0.090622970 0.098224223
 [17] 0.115037664 0.126676341 0.129881732 0.131606385 0.134899426 0.145714057 0.157450178 0.161915807
 [25] 0.172213864 0.175971338 0.179634258 0.186874535 0.201828202 0.203224999 0.203770439 0.233953726
 [33] 0.236048272 0.241850443 0.254187564 0.259881917 0.265276606 0.267579039 0.272713507 0.303959641
 [41] 0.309160002 0.316461361 0.322406952 0.323819903 0.327789129 0.332460332 0.337765366 0.341762770
 [49] 0.357686863 0.362301028 0.366281137 0.372960005 0.374689117 0.388478809 0.390213080 0.421924293
 [57] 0.435661457 0.437150785 0.440334499 0.443767176 0.462212014 0.481747144 0.486371503 0.501200688
 [65] 0.502405247 0.504434890 0.543600542 0.544956015 0.555887094 0.564427247 0.614781724 0.625457450
 [73] 0.672505898 0.678828322 0.681797160 0.693448723 0.695164514 0.723439809 0.733981771 0.746533450
 [81] 0.750223663 0.755690100 0.766753500 0.779076859 0.785195832 0.826792534 0.833149437 0.856594651
 [89] 0.876029762 0.884630133 0.893947590 0.908578042 0.912684937 0.912847511 0.915642401 0.933970693
 [97] 0.950370256 0.954649756 0.981451153 0.989970890
> table(pval>alfa)

FALSE  TRUE 
    8    92
```

You can see that 8 samples out of 100 yielded a p-value smaller than 5%. Had that samples been the result of a real experiment, those 8 times we would have erroneously concluded that the mean in the population mean was different than 0.

Comment: I repeat your experiment,when I increase `n` to 100, `FALSE`number didn't  decrease.That's still the `wrong` from sampling.If we use full sample, is the hypothesis test 100% exact?

Comment: If we cannot use full sample ,each hypothesis test has `0.05` chance to make wrong decision. We always use dozens hypothesis tests in one experiment, how big wrong we made?!

Comment: If we made `0.95` right decision in one step, 10 steps means only `0.95^10` right decision we made.(0.5987369, terrible decision)

Comment: 0.05 is signification, which is set before the experiment and is not going to change. Type I error doesn't change, as seen in my simulation where null hypothesis is true. By increasing sample size we improve type II error rate, that is, probability of accepting null hypothesis when it's false.

Comment: About steps, if you are going to perform several hypothesis tests in sequence, several problems may arise - it's called the multiple comparison problem. If that's your case, I suggest opening a specific question.

Comment: ,I think increase sample size then closer to the population, then type I & II error rate both reduce.

Comment: Most hypothesis tests are build on the assumption that the population is way larger than the sample. If they are close (e.g. population 1000, sample 800), an special study is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and normally distributed but have different means. Suppose we have a sample of size $n > 1$ from each, and the samples happen to be equal. Then so long as the independent-samples $t$ is defined (which just requires each sample to have more than one distinct score), $t = 0$ and hence $p = 1$, even though the null hypothesis is false.

Comment: This is hard to reproduce and can only prove the sampling error.Is that the only error in hypothesis test?

Comment: @WhiteGirl What precisely do you mean by "error"? You said in your question that you wanted to show that hypothesis tests aren't exact. Sampling error is the reason that statistics in general is approximate rather than exact.

Comment: If we use full sample(population),is there any "wrong" made by hypothesis-testing itself?Then we can prove hypothesis-testing is wrong sometimes.

Comment: @WhiteGirl Not if you meet all the formal test assumptions, no. Significance tests are mathematically proven to do what they're advertised to do under the specified conditions.