# How to check whether 2 populations are same by sample?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

sample `a` from population:

`[1]  0.69784958  0.06326852  1.63127812  0.79297830 -0.37361933 -0.20305779 -0.27321559
 [8] -0.06540687  0.90954359  0.41880990  1.20594584  0.68339223 -0.87355712  0.07544178
[15]  0.89045268  0.10113435 -0.73700255 -1.50056032  0.45599269  0.51620615`

sample `b` from population:
`[1]  0.17035324 -0.97052980 -0.09005294 -0.10137240 -1.03429009  0.62668963  1.32530415
 [8]  0.06326852 -0.51194706 -0.54242630 -1.50056032  0.53181168  1.55198989 -0.43028073
[15]  0.60269234 -0.87355712  0.45031117  0.31135434  2.33231072  0.89045268`

I use R to statistics work.`t.test` result is `p-value = 0.7679`, which means 2 populations' mean are equal.
Is that enough to say these 2 populations are same?
Even sd is same,I don't think we can say these 2 populations are same.

Comment: Regarding your earlier question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290512/which-example-can-reveal-hypothesis-test-is-not-always-valid), please accept an answer if one of the answers did in fact answer your question, and if none did, please clarify the question.

Comment: Are you asking about test whether they come from the same *distribution*, without assuming any particular shape? In the usual two-sample equal-variance t-test, under the assumption of sampling from normal distributions and equal variances, the test of equality of means is also a test of equality of distributions as long as the assumptions apply. Are you asking about testing for the same distribution without the assumption of any particular distributional form?

Comment: @Kodiologist,sure,I will,still waiting for more answers.

Comment: @Glen_b,I use t test means the population is normal distribution.But equal mean of normal distribution !=same normal distribution.About the variance, we don't need to assume equal-variance in t test.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to demonstrate. Typically a two sample t-test compares the means of two different populations. Not rejecting the null hypothesis would imply that the population means are equal. Without other information, that's all we can conclude from your result.

Comment: @Flowsnake,you are right. t test doesn't imply same population,only same mean.Then, how to identify same population?

Comment: @WhiteGirl Without the assumption of normality, then I guess you can try the [Kolmorogov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)? Again, a test like this only tests to see if two samples come from the same distribution, not population (although I can see why some would say this is equivalent).

Comment: I already use t test, why do you say `Without the assumption of normality`?

Comment: The t-test assumes that the two samples are from normal distributions. If the samples are big enough, then I guess one can invoke the central limit theorem. But in your case, there are only 20 points in each sample. I wouldn't call that "large".

Comment: @WhiteGirl You don't need to assume equal variance in the t-test if you use the Welch-Satterthwaite version *but then it's no longer a test for equality of distribution, even if all the assumptions hold* ... My point was that there is a t-test (the equal-variance one, which you get in R by putting `var.equal=TRUE` in the argument list) -- with which you can test "are the distributions the same* since with the assumption of equal variance. and normality (as long as they actually hold), the only remaining difference is the mean. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... if you want to test if the distributions are the same *you need to tell us what you're prepared to assume and what you are not prepared to assume*. It would also be useful to know which particular kinds of differences from the same distribution you'd particularly like to be able to pick up. There are many tests that arguably test for equality of distributions, and they have different properties against different alternatives  ... ctd

Comment: ctd... (dozens are intended that way, though arguably there's a very much larger number if we consider that tests where the distributions are the same under the null and different under the alternative are test of equality of distributions in some sense)

Comment: What  do you interpret from p-value  of .7679 ? You do not have a correct understanding of p-value. What t statistic did you get for the data.

Comment: The simple answer to the question is "no", for two reasons.  1) The t-test tests a specific hypothesis about the means of two samples.  Two populations could have exactly the same mean and still be very different populations.  2) A non-significant p-value indicates only that we don't have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis.  Perhaps the two populations are different and we got a non-significance p-value because we don't have enough observations to detect the difference. The conclusion isn't that "They are the same"; it is "We don't have evidence to say they are different."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize so the comments don't become congested:

1) The two sample t-test allows us to determine if the population means of both samples are the same. The test is typically performed under the assumption that both samples come from normal distributions.

2) If the sample size is big enough, then one could still apply the t-test without the normality assumption, but "big enough" is subjective.

3) If you want to avoid assuming underlying distributions, then try the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test.

4) Again, these tests are inferences about the population *distributions*. I'm not sure what you mean by same population.

Comment: The question is too vague and makes self'-styled assertions .Hence, your answer can not be propagated.